# Programmable Keyboard with Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I moved from a Mac keyboard with a Swiss layout to a Windows keyboard with a Canadian layout.

To make my life easier when corresponding in German, I would like to program following key combination to simulate a certain character:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> should simulate <kbd>ö</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> should simulate <kbd>ü</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> should simulate <kbd>ä</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> should simulate <kbd>°</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> should simulate <kbd>DEL</kbd>

As for the last one, I know I could just use <kbd>DEL</kbd> but it happens automatically that I still want to use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>.

Can I achieve this with Windows 10? And how?

(I am aware of that I can change keyboards with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.)

Comment: [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can map any key.

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without installing a separate software as well?